# Error: Unexpected token: punc ()

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

I'm trying to build my project that uses webpack. My UglifyJS options looks like this:

```
new UglifyJSPlugin({
            sourceMap: false,
            uglifyOptions: {
              compress: {
                warnings: false,
              },
              output: {
                comments: false,
              },
            },
          }),
```

What I get is an error:
`Unexpected token: punc ()) [index-3d0ae630eaa0a0128a00.js:145853,20]`

I have found some SO topic saying that this might be a problem with webpack uglify plugin, but I've already switched to an `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I got this error when I added an arrow function () => , which is ES6, and uglify only supports ES5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error and was able to fix it by:

1. Upgrading to the 1.0.0-beta.2 (`npm i -D uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@beta`)
2. Adding `"uglifyjs": true` to the targets in `babel-preset-env`

If you're using the env preset, try updating the targets in your `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "uglify": true
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

There is also [an issue on the plugin repo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) that lists other possible solutions.