# webpack errors out when using -p flag

Tags: reactjs, webpack

If I run this command:

```
rimraf docs/public/assets && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js"
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR in app.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: punc (,) [./node_modules/@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons/index.es.js:10344,0][app.bundle.js:12196,10]
```

but if I remove `-p` in webpack command, I wont get the error anymore.

What is -p for? Appreciates if anyone can shed some lights in this behaviour.

Comment: Which version of webpack are you using? The `-p` flag means “mode: production”, i.e. webpack uses Uglify to minify your code. The “punc” error is a common issue of webpack versions earlier than 4, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781808/error-unexpected-token-punc

Comment: I'm using webpack 3.12 and looks like the error is cause by webpack not recognizing es6 syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after half a day of debugging, I resolved this with the following updates:

in `package.json`: `"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0"`

in `webpack.config.js` : `const UglifyJsPlugin    = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');`

and under `plugins` :

```
plugins: [
..........
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
              sourceMap: true,
              cache: true,
              parallel: true,
              uglifyOptions: {
                warnings: false,
                parse: {},
                compress: {},
                mangle: true, 
                output: null
              }
            }),
]
```

Updating to webpack4 creates more issues than it fixes so it wasn't an option for me since I have too many dependencies that aren't compatible with webpack4. What I need was just a simple minifier. 
Hope this helps everyone.